# Cross compile ARM on OSX x86-64

Tags: ios, c, xcode, macos, llvm

I want to compile a simple **helloworld.c** on my **Mac** and then send it to my **iphone 4** to run.

the code is pretty simple:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main( ) {
printf("Hello, world!\n");
return 0;
}
```

**My setup:**

> OSX El Capitain 10.11
>
> Xcode 7.2
>
> Iphone4 with iOS 7.1.4 JB
>
> clang -v Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81) Target:
>   x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0 Thread model: posix
>
> gcc -v Configured with:
>   --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1 Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81) Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0 Thread model: posix
>
> iPhoneOS9.0.2.sdk

All the info that I found on the web are not useful, because of new Xcode or because of the new compilers on recent OSX.

Comment: Why would you want that at all, anyways? It's not that it could run on a non-jailbroken device if it crosscompiled.

Comment: just for educational purpose :)
I figured it out: using clang  -isysroot $(xcrun --sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-path) -arch armv7  hello.c -o hello

Comment: OP, consider [answering your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) then :)

Answer (score 7):

The correct configuration for the compiler was

```
clang -isysroot $(xcrun --sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-path) -arch armv7 hello.c -o hello
```

This will produce a arm binary unsigned.

If your JB device need file signing, use ldid for this.